# Proving nowhere-differentiability for given function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm working on a problem in a real analysis course and I think I'm somewhat lost. It's a three part problem and I believe that I have solved the first two problems but I'm now lost at the final.

I've been given a set $A=\{f\in C([0,1]): f(1)=1, f(0)=0\}$ and I've proven that it is complete with respect to the infinity metric $d(f,g)=\text{sup}|f(x)-g(x)|$.

I'm then given an operator taking $C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ by

$Tf(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{4}f(3x) & x\in[0,\frac{1}{3}],\\
\frac{1}{2}f(2-3x) + \frac{1}{4} & x\in(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}],\\
\frac{3}{4}f(3x-2) + \frac{1}{4} & x\in(\frac{2}{3},1]
\end{cases}$

which I have shown is a subset of A and also that $Tf(x)$ is a contraction, which means that the Fixed Point Theorem holds and thus that there exists a unique $f$ such that $Tf(x)=f(x)$.

However, what I'm asked to prove next is that $f$ is $\text{nowhere differentiable}$. This is where I get stuck.

I've attempted a proof by contradiction, assuming that $f$ is differentiable for some $a\in [0,1]$, dividing into three cases (one for every given interval) and then appealing to definition.

For Case I, I get:

$lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$

I then use the fact that $Tf(x)=f(x)$, plug in my values for Case I and get:

$lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{3}{4}f(3a+3h)-\frac{3}{4}f(3a)}{h}$

But I'm not sure how to get rid of the $h$ in the numerator here and the same problem rings true for all three cases. I want to find something in either the continuity of $f$ or the completeness of $A$ such that I can find a contradiction but I'm not sure where to look. Do I want to bound the limit? Is there some obvious connection that I haven't made? In what direction should I look?

Another way to write the limit that I assume could be helpful is by writing it as

$f(a+h)-f(a)=f'(a)h+r(h)\Leftrightarrow \frac{3}{4}(f(3a+3h)-f(3a))=\frac{9}{4}f'(3a)+r(h)$

Where $r(h)$ is some term for which $\frac{r(h)}{h}$ goes to $0$ when $h$ goes to $0$ but again I'm not sure how to continue with this equation in hopes of finding a contradiction.

I would be very grateful for any kind of hints or help. Thanks. Apologies if this has been asked before, I've searched online for similar problems but I've been unable to find similar ones that deal with the nowhere differentiability.

Comment: I haven't solved it either, but maybe there's something to be had considering $lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{3}{4}f(3a+3h)-f(a)}{h}$ ?

Comment: @TomCollinge I'm not sure how the limit on this form is any more helpful, I believe that the constant won't be a problem but instead the fact that we can't get rid of the h in the numerator.
Maybe if we use the fact T is a contraction? The inequality I end up with through proof of contractivity is d(Tf, Tg) <= 3/4 d(f,g) and it is the only possible bound I can think of in this case.